# Getter and setter for userVisibleHint is deprecated, Deprecated in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Getter and setter for userVisibleHint is deprecated, Deprecated in Java
How to fix this ?!

I used this code, but the android studio tells me that 'userVisibleHint' is deprecated.

```
        val fm = childFragmentManager
        if (handleBackPressed(fm)) {
            return true
        } else if (userVisibleHint && fm.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack()
            return true
        }
        return false
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to list one "." after the name of the class, and then mention the name of the attribute to access it:

```
getter: class.property
setter: class.property = value
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand, which class you mean?
If you mean the class that contains this method, the same thing will happen!

Comment: i think userVisibleHint is a class. for access a property from userVisibleHint class you should use that form.maybe i don't understand your question.

Comment: @Amir No, it's likely a property name (for `Fragment`)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) you can see that the entire `android.app.Fragment` class is deprecated and you should switch to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Its `get/setUserVisibleHint` methods [are not deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()).

Comment: Actually I am using 'import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint() says "Deprecated: Use FragmentTransaction#setMaxLifecycle(Fragment, Lifecycle.State) instead." but it isn't clear _how_ you are supposed to use it.